# FSL : Not able to Search Product field in Quick action from flow

Tags: visual-workflow, quickaction, field-service-lightning, fsl

**BackGround**

I am facing a weird issue related to quick action and flow, I have created FSL Mobile flow, and inside the flow, I am using quick action, which is creating Work Order Line Record, in Quick action, I have added a product field on action layout which is a lookup to pricebookentry, but when I launched the flow from Ipad/Android FSL App, I am not able to search product and link to quick action.

Flow Logic :

1. Screen - radio button with two option(Installation or Service)
2. Decision - If Installation calling Installation Quick Action or Vice Versa
3. When Quick action launched, In the product field, I am not able to search any record(Note: I have added price book as well in Work Order)

**If i remove first screen from flow it is working and i am search the product from ipad but not from Android. Not Sure what is problem in Flow and quick action**, Please advice why product lookup search not working.

**Flow**
[image]

**Quick Action**

[image]

**Action Fields**

[image]

**FSL App Screenshot**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The limitations of Flows in the Field Service Lightning is clearly documented.

1. Screen flows launched using quick actions or app extensions aren't supported.

   Hence you are seeing that you have to remove the screen elements.
2. Flows don’t support the Actions with output parameters

> NOTE Some flows that have actions with output parameters don't cause an error immediately, but they’re still not supported.

All of the above has been documented [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mfs_limits.htm&type=5)

These limitations are there because the Field Service Mobile app is designed to work [offline](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mfs_offline_considerations.htm&type=5) [securely](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mfs_security.htm&type=5) and hence supporting flows is been challenging

There are a couple of pilots running for LWC support for Field Service! You should work with your Account executive or Program Architect to learn more about these

Comment: Hi @mohith, thanks for your response, but in Quick Action, there is also another lookup field Asset, which is working fine, I am getting the data, the issue with the product field only, and maybe an issue with the FSL app.

Comment: I think best bet is to raise a support case! Note that the limitations still apply as documented!

Answer (score -1):

as a workaround u can try to create lwc action and then call your flow

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/206602)

Comment: actually it is the answer

Comment: If you believe this is correct can you add a little more detail? It's a bit short right now